# Not able to convert DBCursor to JSON array {MongoDB }"Could not write content: JSONObject is not assignable to JSONArray "

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, jackson

I am newbie, forgive me if this sounds silly.

I am trying to convert a cursor returned by mongo collection into a json object. Such that, when I hit this particular url(`localhost:8080/TestReqHere`) I receive a list of model object in json format. But the code below does  not work as expected.

Note that if i do `table.find().toArray()` and change the return type to `List<DBObject>` it works fine. I get a json like response.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {    
@RequestMapping(value = { "/TestReqHere" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<JSONArray> getTestReqHere( HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();

            MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = mongo.getDB("someList");
            DBCollection table = db.getCollection("someList");
            DBCursor cursor = table.find();
              while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
                jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                jsonobj.put("col1", obj.getString("col1"));
                jsonobj.put("col2", obj.getString("col2"));
                jsonobj.put("_id", obj.getString("_id"));

                jsonarray.add(jsonobj);
              }
            return jsonarray;

        }
```

A normal program to convert object to / from JSON using Jackson works fine for me but when run on server I get the below error: Could you please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not write content: Class 
org.json.simple.JSONObject is not assignable to 
org.json.simple.JSONArray (through reference chain: 
    org.json.simple.JSONArray[0]); nested exception is 
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class 
    org.json.simple.JSONObject is not assignable to org.json.simple.JSONArray 
    (through reference chain: org.json.simple.JSONArray[0])
```